# How to multiply a matrix of % of grand totals to value to create predicted values in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

In Power BI, I have a matrix of known values, and a matrix with the data again but as % of grand total. I would like to multiply the % of grand total by an independent number, to make a new matrix with some forecast values.

For example, if I have 60 units

```
A      10     20

B      20    10
```

The % of grand totals:

```
A     17%     33%

B     33%     17%
```

Is it possible to then have another table with potential values, which I can pick using a slider, and multiply by the grand totals to get a predicted value? Let's say if I pick '200', the resulting table would look like this:

```
A     33.3     66.7

B     66.7     33.3
```

I've tried using parameters, calculated tables and measures but at best end up with a matrix in which every cell is identically filled with the predicted value eg 200.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to use a measure to accomplish this. Have you tried something along the lines of:

```
Predicted Values Measure = 
DIVIDE (
[Your Current Measure],
CALCULATE ( [Your Current Measure], ALL ( 'Table1'[Value1] ) ) ) * 200
```

If you had a slider of potential values you might be able to use SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table1'[Slicer1] ) or something similar instead of specifying the value (e.g., "200") in the measure.